# Should the threshold for post closure by non-moderators be reduced from 5 to 3?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, vote-to-close

Essentially, because voting activity on SE:AI is still sub-optimal, it's rare for a question to recieve 5 close votes from the community.

(Here the community refers to non-moderators--mods can close at will.)

I personally like this because it's better when closures represent the will of the community, as opposed to the will of an individual moderator, in all but exception cases where the question or answer clearly causes harm.

Note: I only feel comfortable proposing this b/c members of our community tend to adhere to the "be nice" policy, and are generally seeking to help the OP by asking for more clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Some of you may have noticed the Meta Stack Exchange post - [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites) (it's linked in the featured on meta sidebar) - we've finally got this project under way and Artificial Intelligence is one of the sites we'll be running the test on.

Starting tomorrow, I'll be changing the site setting and closing and reopening will require only three votes. This test will run for 45 days and will be turned back to five votes to close and reopen while I review the data from the 13 sites. After we've seen the impact, I'll be posting results and, if there aren't negative impacts, we will change the setting to three permanently.

A few weeks into this, I'll be posting a question here on meta to ask for your thoughts about this change, so you will have an opportunity to discuss the impact.

Thank you so much for your patience while we got this prioritized and scheduled. There's a lot more information in the MSE post, so please review it.

Comment: Catija, thanks for the heads-up, and I'm glad we'll be testing this on SE:AI.  As a thriving small stack with typically lower voting participation, I suspect this will have utility here.

Comment: Hello Catija! Thanks for addressing this issue. I really think our community almost never closes a post with 5 votes nowadays. By the way, we have a post on the review queue, which has 4 upvotes, so it should have been already closed, but it wasn't yet.  See [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27635/2444). (Update: it was finally closed with 5 votes!)