# Is Searching for finding some information ( Papers or Posts) about the AI simulation with Time traveling capability off topic

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange post: [About AI time traveling capability](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/about-ai-time-traveling-capability)

I guess, I specially have said there, that i am trying to find some information ( Papers or Posts) about the **AI simulation with Time traveling capability**.

So i asked here to find out what part of the above question was on topic or unclear which is closed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That post was closed after the vote of 3 community members (including myself). It would have been closed anyway even if I was not a moderator, given that, right now, [only 3 votes are required to close a post on this site](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1730/2444). The post was later *automatically* deleted by the system (the system automatically deletes posts that have no answer and have been downvoted after a while).

So, what is unclear in your post? Many things. For example, I don't understand the following paragraph

> Based of ai nature(needs to information and Calculayion unit) I guess, it could do the time traveling in the our univerese by finding some calculation unit for doing it's calculation and do its calculation for funding the challenge of time traveling puzzles like

Why don't I understand this paragraph? Here are a few questions that come to my mind after having read it.

1. What is "ai nature"?
2. What's the meaning of "(needs to information and Calculayion unit)" and how is it related to "ai nature"?
3. ...

I could go on and on, but I guess it should be clear now that the post was unclear. If this was just a "language issue", I would suggest that you write the post in your language first, then use Google Translate or DeepL to translate from your native language to English. Moreover, before posting again, please, take some time to correct the typos and read [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).